# How can I give Ember Data model a TTL and reload it after it expires?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

If the application is supposed to be used over a longer preiod of time where mutiple users operate over the same data, it might happen that the things one user has in his local cache don't exist anymore.

For example user might view a post with it's comments, which are loaded as a nested data under the post. This means he will do only one request in the begining with `GET /posts/1`, but after that, the post will be always loaded from the cache.

But if another user posts a comment, he will never find that out, unless he reloads the whole page, which will reset the identity map.

**Is there any way that I can expire the data after a while, forcing it to re-load for example each 5 minutes? Or is there an alternative way that I should consider to solve this issue?**

***edit: There actually isn't any way to do this so far. I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/545) and keep working on it and post the result as an answer here when it is done.***

Comment: *"but after that, the post will be always loaded from the cache."* - Why?

Comment: @Tomalak because ember uses identity map to "cache" things on the client side. That way it doesn't have to do a request each time you request a record by it's ID.

Comment: I see... unfortunately I'm not qualified to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using websockets would be a better solution. Unfortunately, there is no existing websockets adapter for Ember-data yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)) to reload it. Perhaps you could set this up in the router. On entering the router, set an interval that reloads the model every 5 minutes (perhaps only if it's in a certain state). On exiting the route, clear the interval.

Comment: That won't work for scenario when I don't know where the model was loaded from. You can only do this for example if you're connecting outlets manually. But if the data is loaded via something like hasMany relation, you can't specify a `setInterval` to reload the data.